# Initialize IWDG with two difference handles

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, watchdog

I am implementing a watchdog in my project, where i am using a IWDG in STM32F4 series controller. I am trying to initialize the watchdog twice with different handles, since it is implemented in two different tasks. As per functionality wise it is working with no problems, but when i reviewed my code, I found that I have initailized the IWDG twice with same instance but different handles passed. 
My initialization is as follows,

```
IWDG_HandleTypeDef rIWDG;
IWDG_HandleTypeDef rIWDG1;
void IWDG_vInit(void)
{

   rIWDG.Instance = IWDG;
   rIWDG.Init.Prescaler = IWDG_PRESCALER;
   rIWDG.Init.Reload = IWDG_RELOAD_VALUE;
   if (HAL_IWDG_Init(&rIWDG) != HAL_OK)
   {
      //Error Handler
   }

   rIWDG1.Instance = IWDG;
   rIWDG1.Init.Prescaler = IWDG_PRESCALER_256;
   rIWDG1.Init.Reload = IWDG_WINDOW_VALUE1;
   if (HAL_IWDG_Init(&rIWDG1) != HAL_OK)
   {
      // Error Handler
   }

}
```

Is this a problem? Am i allowed to initialize this way? If its wrong how is it working fine with proper window values.

Thank You.

Comment: That is a pure software issue you can figure out by looking at HAL code and running with a debugger what it does at init, which one of the initializations are run first and last to know which initialization is in effect, and how the values in the handle are used when resetting the watchdog.

Comment: As per initialization it shows two handles have their specific values as per initialization. I am more interested in knowing whether it is wrong to initialize this way?

Comment: If the watchdog peripheral and the HAL is okay with multiple initializations, and the code reliably works during the time that the watchdog is initialized with wrong parameters, and it is not close to reset before reinitializing it, then it is not wrong. But most likely it is just not a good way of doing it, if you can improve it by initializing only once with correct parameters, and with a single handle so there is no memory reserved for two handles.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one IWDG peripheral.

If you want to share the HAL instance of the IWDG you have to link the handle across compilation units with the `extern` keyword.

Or use the IWDG registers directly.

[image]

---

Also, the design of sharing the IWDG [smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), you may want to reconsider the design here.
http://www.ganssle.com/tem/tem365.html
http://www.ganssle.com/item/great-watchdog-timers.htm